# How to get right/left arrows on Activity to indicate more screens to the right/left?

Tags: android, scroll, android-activity, viewflipper

I have a ViewFlipper which contains a few linear layouts.

I need to allow the user to flip through them.

I've seen other apps which have arrow/triangle indicators on either side of the screen, which, when pressed, flips to the next view in the set.

I'd like to add these to my Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not included in the ViewFlipper by default. You have to implement it by yourself. For that just define two Images where you wan't to show the arrows. Then you can use the methods getDisplayedChild() und getChildCount() to calculate if there is a next/previous flipper. According to that you can set your arrow images.